# Django - distinct rows/objects distinguished by date/day from datetime field

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime

I'v searched quite a while now and know about several answers on sof but none of the solutions does work at my end even if my problem is pretty simple:

What I need (using postgres + django 1.10): I have many rows with many duplicate dates (=days) within a datetime field. I want a queryset containing one row/object each date/day.

```
fk | col1 | colX | created (type: datetime)
----------------------------------------------
1  | info | info | 2016-09-03 08:25:52.142617+00:00 <- get it (time does not matter)
1  | info | info | 2016-09-03 16:26:52.142617+00:00
2  | info | info | 2016-09-03 11:25:52.142617+00:00
1  | info | info | 2016-09-14 16:26:52.142617+00:00 <- get it (time does not matter)
3  | info | info | 2016-09-14 11:25:52.142617+00:00
1  | info | info | 2016-09-25 23:25:52.142617+00:00 <- get it (time does not matter)
1  | info | info | 2016-09-25 16:26:52.142617+00:00
1  | info | info | 2016-09-25 11:25:52.142617+00:00
2  | info | info | 2016-09-25 14:27:52.142617+00:00
2  | info | info | 2016-09-25 16:26:52.142617+00:00
3  | info | info | 2016-09-25 11:25:52.142617+00:00
etc.
```

Whats the best (performance + pythionic/django) way to do this. My model/table is going to have many rows (>million).

**EDIT 1**

The results must be filtered by a fk (e.g. WHERE fk = 1) first.

I already tried the most obvious things such as

```
MyModel.objects.filter(fk=1).order_by('created__date').di‌​stinct('created__dat‌​e')
```

but got following error:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'date' into field. Join on 'created' not permitted.

...same error with all() and respective ordering through class Meta instead of query-method order_by()...

Does somebody maybe know more about this error in this specific case?

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't seem to be possible given the current Django implementation, as this would involve using advanced DB backend functions (like [Postgres window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-window.html)).

The closest thing you've got is to use aggregations :

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(
    created_date=TruncDay('created')
).values('created_date').annotate(id=Min('id'))
```

This would aggregate over the similar dates, and pick-up the minimal id.

```
[{'created_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 16), 'id': 146},
 {'created_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 28), 'id': 188},
 {'created_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 24), 'id': 178},
 {'created_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 23), 'id': 171},
 {'created_date': datetime.date(2017, 3, 22), 'id': 157}] ...
```

If you need the whole objects, you can chain this with a `.values_list()` and another query set, which would result in a subquery:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(
    id__in=MyModel.objects.annotate(
        created_date=TruncDay('created')
    ).values('created_date').annotate(id=Min('id')).values_list(
        'id', flat=True
    )
)
```

FYI this results in the following query

```
SELECT
    "myapp_mymodel"."id",
    "myapp_mymodel"."created",
    "myapp_mymodel"."col1",
    "myapp_mymodel"."colX"
FROM "myapp_mymodel"
WHERE "myapp_mymodel"."id" IN (
    SELECT MIN(U0."id") AS "id"
    FROM "myapp_mymodel" U0
    GROUP BY DATE(U0."created")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a similar issue - not with `order_by()` or `distinct()`, but with `filter()`. I am using Django 1.9, but that might not make any difference here.

In one of my apps in one model, `filter(datetime_field__date__lt=(date(2016, 12, 5)))` works fine, in another model in a different app within the same project, I get the same error as you.

In my case, it looks as if `django-money` (https://github.com/django-money/django-money) causes the problem. As far as I can tell by now, the `money_manager()` function from `djmoney.models.managers` breaks the `__date` lookup (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#date).

When I attach another manager not named `objects`, for example `testmanager = models.Manager()`, to the relevant model without wrapping it in `money_manager()`, the `__date` lookup works fine again, without any other changes to the model or the database.

I have not yet found a fully satisfying solution, but maybe you also use `django-money` or another **third-party application that messes around with the default manager**? Perhaps the **traceback** gives any hints about which package might be the problem.

My traceback looks like this: 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/[...]/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/[...]/python3.4/site-packages/djmoney/models/managers.py", line 164, in wrapper
    args, kwargs = _expand_money_kwargs(model, args, kwargs, exclusions)
  File "/[...]/python3.4/site-packages/djmoney/models/managers.py", line 136, in _expand_money_kwargs
    elif isinstance(_get_field(model, name), MoneyField):
  File "/[...]/python3.4/site-packages/djmoney/models/managers.py", line 63, in _get_field
    field = qs.setup_joins(parts, opts, alias)[0]
  File "/[...]/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1405, in setup_joins
    names, opts, allow_many, fail_on_missing=True)
  File "/[...]/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1373, in names_to_path
    " not permitted." % (names[pos + 1], name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'date' into field. Join on 'my_datetime_field' not permitted.`

Comment: Fyi - the issue I experienced with `django-money` was indeed a bug and it has now already been fixed in the master branch: https://github.com/django-money/django-money/issues/241

Answer (score -2):

you can use a Queryset to get the results from your table by a distinct on the created value because you are using postgresql.

Maybe a query like this should do the work :

```
MyModel.objects.all().distinct('created__date')
```

I refer you too the queryset documentation of django : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Comment: if this works as i think it would, shouldn't it be `.distinct('created__date')` ?

Comment: Yeah that's right, didn't see the 'time does not matter' in the post. Answer edited.

Comment: ...this is one of the most obvious solutions which if tried with following error:

Comment: my query is slightly different:

Comment: `MyModel.objects.filter(xyz=123).order_by('created__date').distinct('created__date')`

_django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'date' into field. Join on 'created' not permitted._

Comment: ...same error with all() and respective ordering through class Meta instead of query-method order_by()...
Nervertheless: Forgot to say thanks you for answering! Now I just need a working solution... :)

Comment: Maybe if you in first time get all your date, and then do an another queryset for your entries, filtered by dates :
`my_dates = MyModel.objects.all().values('created__date').distinct()`

`datas = MyModel.objects.all().filter(created__date__in=my_dates).distinct()`

Obviously you have to adapt yours queryset in concordance of what you got in your model.